# Uncaught SyntaxError in JS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm adding a JS file to Html yet I'm getting a syntax error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

```html
    <script src="./includes/vuetags/main.js" ></script>
```

JS file (main.js) - the error is traced by chrome to line 1

```js
import VoerroTagsInput from './VoerroTagsInput.vue';

window.VoerroTagsInput = VoerroTagsInput;

export default VoerroTagsInput
```

Any ideas why it tells me I have an error?

> Ended up finding that this action requires running Vuejs CLI (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the error is not in line 1 of "main.js" (the file you show), but in line 1 of the included "VoerroTagsInput.vue".  A "*.vue" file is a custom file format that uses HTML-like syntax to describe a Vue component.  Thus, you cannot import JavaScript code from there.

Comment: So how do I import the file shown here: https://github.com/voerro/vue-tagsinput/tree/master/src ?

Comment: @RoyGranit I have no idea, but it really does not look like it's JavaScript.

Comment: Working with .vue files requires a more advanced set of tools. Refer to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html to get the idea behind the concept.